# Woocommerce REST API No TAX applied on New Order Via REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm working on site, built on Wordpress with Woocommerce for product selling. 
When customer buy products via website, it works perfect and tax based on customer's Country, State, & City applied on whole item.

The same procedure I need to achieve via [Woocommerce REST API - Order Complete](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/wp-api-v2.html?php#order-properties). version 2.

I'm using a postman collection and prepare a order data and hits the end-point

```
{POST}wp-json/wc/v2/orders
```

Everything works perfect, billing address, shipping address, customer notes. But there is no TAX added on order created via REST API. 
Please advise or share any example to how I can achieve it manually via PHP or by Woocommerce Hooks.

[image]

Comment: {{baseUrl}} means the link for example: "http://example.com"

Comment: The same problem applies to me. And I started a bounty. I hope someone knows this.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can calculate using this script.

```
function calculate_tax($country, $state, $postcode, $city, $tax_class = '') {
    $tax_rates = WC_Tax::find_rates([
        'country' => $country,
        'state' => $state,
        'postcode' => $postcode,
        'city' => $city,
        'tax_class' => $tax_class
    ]);

    return $tax_rates;
}
```

```
$tax_rates = calculate_tax($country, $state, $postcode, $city);

// Prepare line items with tax
$line_items = [];

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $tax_rate = WC_Tax::get_rate($tax_rates[0]['rate_id']);
    $tax_amount = WC_Tax::calc_tax($product['price'], $tax_rate, true);

    $line_items[] = [
        'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
        'quantity' => $product['quantity'],
        'subtotal' => $product['price'],
        'total' => $product['price'],
        'taxes' => [
            [
                'id' => $tax_rates[0]['rate_id'],
                'total' => $tax_amount,
                'subtotal' => $tax_amount
            ]
        ]
    ];
}
```

```
$order_data = [
    // ... other order data ...
    'line_items' => $line_items
];

// Create the order using the WooCommerce REST API client
$client->post('orders', $order_data);
```

Answer (score -2):

In postman {{baseUrl}} means the link to your webiste let "http://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/orders". In the place of "https://example.com/" replace with your own website URL of woo commerce.